# How to keep HTTP session open

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to keep HTTP connection open from my client to my web server, and send every 2 second GET request, I tried the following code, and I see on my web server (using netstat -na |grep 8000) that I have ~30 open connections (concurrent) which are closing and opening.
so my code is not keeping the connection open.
Here is my code:

```
    def GetRestFromGW_Thread(self, gw_ip, runningDir):
    URL = "http://" + gw_ip + ":8000/Status.c"
    Error = 0
    session = requests.Session()
    headers = {'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*',
               'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.13.0'}
    response = session.get(URL, headers=headers, timeout=5)
    while True:
        # print("Sending HTTP GET")
        try:
            response.raise_for_status()
            # print(response)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                # print(response.json())
                # print("WRITING TO LOCAL FILE")
                try:
                    with open(runningDir + "/GwRest.json", 'w') as outfile:
                        json.dump(response.json(), outfile)
                        outfile.close()
                        Error = 0
                except Exception as e:
                    print("ERRROR:" + str(e))
                    pass
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
            print("HTTPError: " + str(errh))
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
            print("Got ConnectionError number: " + str(Error))
            Error = Error + 1
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
            print("Timeout: " + str(errt))
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            print("RequestException: " + str(err))
        time.sleep(2)
        if Error >= 30:
            break
```

Comment: Have you heard about websockets ?

Comment: no, can you refer me to it?
also so what you say is that there isn't any way to accomplish what I am trying with HTTP session?

Comment: also consider I cannot install new packages on the web server